# Use Python Logging with twisted

Tags: python, logging, twisted

I know how to make [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) use python logging ([docs](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/logging.html#auto3))

But normal python logging is still swallowed. Print-statements are visible, but `logger.warn('...')` is not.

I use this logging set up in my library which I want to use from twisted:

```
import logging
logger=logging.getLogger(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))

class Foo:
    def foo(self):
        logger.warn('...')
```

I don't want to change my library to use twisted logging, since the library is already used in a lot of projects which don't use twisted.

If I google for this problem, I only find solutions which pipe the twisted logs in to the python logging.

How can I view see the logging of my library (without changing it)?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that Twisted is asynchronous, and avoids doing blocking I/O wherever possible. However, stdlib logging is not asynchronous, and so it does blocking I/O, and the two can't easily mix because of this. You may be able to achieve some measure of cooperation between them if you e.g. use a `QueueHandler` (introduced in the stdlib in Python 3.2 and mentioned [here](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/logging-cookbook.html#dealing-with-handlers-that-block), but available to earlier versions through the [`logutils`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/logutils) project). You can use this handler (and this handler only) to deal with events sent using stdlib logging, and your corresponding `QueueListener` can dispatch the events received using Twisted (non-blocking) I/O. It should work, as the queue handler shouldn't block if created with no finite capacity, and assuming that the I/O sinks can get rid of the events quickly enough (otherwise, memory would fill up).

Comment: I think you may have answered a question that is the opposite of what the poster asked.  If the log events arrive via `logging` then there should be no problem delivering them to Twisted's logging system.  If the expectation (by the `logging` module) is that a log consumer is going to block and then the consumer doesn't block, what harm has been done?

Comment: @Jean-Paul Calderone: Perhaps wrongly, I got the impression that a third-party module which uses stdlib logging may be involved. To deliver events from such modules into Twisted's non-blocking outputs from stdlib loggers, then the user needs to use a non-blocking handler such as `QueueHandler` and have the corresponding `QueueListener` talk to the non-blocking I/O sinks - IIUC.

Comment: Why?  Twisted's non-blocking handler will ... not ... block.  There is no problem here for QueueHandler to solve.  QueueHandler would be useful if there were *blocking* log handlers in Twisted then QueueHandler would be useful to deliver events to them *without* blocking.  But there aren't (as far as can be discerned from the original question).

Comment: Right, but handlers are the way to get events out of stdlib logging to external destinations. All the other handlers provided by stdlib logging are blocking handlers, so unless there is some other handler for stdlib logging which interfaces with Twisted for I/O, I'm suggesting `QueueHandler` to bridge the gap. This is to bridge the API gap, not anything else. OTOH if Twisted has a handler for stdlib logging which can be plugged in to a stdlib logger using `addHandler`, that would be better - is there such a thing?

Comment: AFAICT, the twisted uses normal python file() and write() calls. It even uses the built-in syslog module for syslog logging. So... nothing different than what you would get with the stdlib?

Answer (score 0):

utils/log.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import logging
import logging.handlers
from logging.config import dictConfig

from twisted.python.failure import Failure
from twisted.python import log as twisted_log

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

DEFAULT_LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'loggers': {
        'twisted':{
            'level': 'ERROR',
        }
    }
}
def failure_to_exc_info(failure):
    """Extract exc_info from Failure instances"""
    if isinstance(failure, Failure):
        return (failure.type, failure.value, failure.getTracebackObject())

def configure_logging(logfile_path):
    """
    Initialize logging defaults for Project.

    :param logfile_path: logfile used to the logfile
    :type logfile_path: string

    This function does:

    - Assign INFO and DEBUG level to logger file handler and console handler
    - Route warnings and twisted logging through Python standard logging

    """
    observer = twisted_log.PythonLoggingObserver('twisted')
    observer.start()

    dictConfig(DEFAULT_LOGGING)

    default_formatter = logging.Formatter(
        "[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] [%(name)s] [%(funcName)s():%(lineno)s] [PID:%(process)d TID:%(thread)d] %(message)s",
        "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

    file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(logfile_path, maxBytes=10485760,backupCount=300, encoding='utf-8')
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    file_handler.setFormatter(default_formatter)
    console_handler.setFormatter(default_formatter)

    logging.root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logging.root.addHandler(file_handler)
    logging.root.addHandler(console_handler)
```

hello.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.resource import Resource


class BasicPage(Resource):
    isLeaf = True

    def render_GET(self, request):
        logger.info("<html><body><h1>Basic Test</h1><p>This is a basic test page.</p></body></html>")
        return "<html><body><h1>Basic Test</h1><p>This is a basic test page.</p></body></html>"

def hello():
    logger.info("Basic web server started.  Visit http://localhost:8000.")
    root = BasicPage()
    factory = Site(root)
    reactor.listenTCP(8000, factory)
    reactor.run()
    exit()
```

main.py

```
def main():
configure_logging('logfilepath')
hello.hello()
```

Comment: Instead "RotatingFileHandler" how can I use DailyLogFile? With logformatter.